# how to retrive data from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrive data from firebase realtime database. in database have child called "Users" inside of that child have another child called "recently_played" inside of that have list of items only save items id in "recently_played" child.

```
if (currentUser != null) {
                        String userId = currentUser.getUid();
                        DatabaseReference recentlyPlayedRef = databaseReference.child("Users").child(userId).child("recently_played");      
                        recentlyPlayedRef.child(itemid).setValue(true); 

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "Please log in to save as recently played.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

And I created recyclerView for display each items. each items have details (title,speakers,duration,category). I want to implement get items id from "recently_played" child and I created another different child called "speeches" and all items data store inside of "speeches" child with ech itemid and get each items data from "speeches" child and display each items inside in recycleview with itemcards.I also created itemModel , mainAdapter classes for retrive data to cards(i also created card layout called "single_item.xml"). I tryed to implement this but it's not working. My mentioned bellow.

```
recentlyPlayedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("Users")
                        .child(currentUser.getUid())
                        .child("recently_played");
                Query query;
                query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("speeches")
                        .child(String.valueOf(recentlyPlayedRef));

                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ItemModel> options =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>()
                                .setQuery(query, ItemModel.class)
                                .build();

                mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(options);
                recentlyrecycleview.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
                mainAdapter.startListening();
```

I want to display each items with cards inside of recycleview. Items id have in "recently_played" child and get each items data from "speeches" child using items id. And i already created itemModel class and MainAdapter for retrive data to card.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?